# how to customize display of very long drop down list in magento

Tags: magento, php

[image]I have many subcategories to be displayed in home page, but it is vertically too long,, i want to make it scroll on hover. what changes need to be done in css or other files, please guide me script which is responsive

reference:https://css-tricks.com/examples/LongDropdowns/ i want scolling of list as in referred website mentioned above

Comment: you can show sub navigation in multiple columns

Comment: please can u guide me any script to add in magento

Answer (score 0):

i dont know magento,  but here looking like you have given scroll to your page. you need to set fix height of your menu and set vertical scroll to drop down so it will scroll only menu's in drop down otherwise whole page will scroll

Comment: i dont want scroll in my drop down menu, just it has to scroll on mouse over by itself.. like the above link shows,, or atleast i want just to display arrows to move down.

Answer (score 0):

You can set width of `<UL>` (for example: 500px) and then set width of `<li>` under it to approx half of width of `<UL>`.

You can take reference from http://www.gramercydrugs.com/ or http://www.welcaresupply.com/.

Please let me know if you have any problem.

Comment: this is my class where i have changed width,, and its working,, but where to change the li class so that other elements comes at top,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,.nav-primary li.level0 ul {
    background: #FBFBFB;
    border: solid 1px #cccccc;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 30px;
    /* Height of ".nav-primary a.level0" */
    z-index: 10;
    width: 500px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    display: none;
    /* Hide until displayed. */
  }

Comment: can you send me URL of website where you are working?