# Dealing with large categories in Magento 2 menu

Tags: menu, frontend, magento2

I have a category in Magento 2 that has 368 subcategories making the dropdown menu for that category too long.  I have a theme with the megamenu extension, and I was wondering if there was a good way to deal with a category like this.  I am considering getting an extension that allows you to create a page with all of these subcategories as links, but I am wondering if there is a way to do it with the megamenu I already have.  The only answer I have been able to find on the internet was this Stack Overflow answer [how to customize display of very long drop down list in magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32963530/how-to-customize-display-of-very-long-drop-down-list-in-magento), but I don't want to use a scroll on hover option.  I was wondering if anyone knew a good way to deal with a very long categories, especially if it can be done using a megamenu.

Comment: I have one other category that has 41 subcategories making the dropdown menu just a little too long.  Even if a solution may not be manageable for 368 subcategories, I would also like to know about solutions that might work for this smaller case.